# connecting from android mobile app to a database on a laptop

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programming so please I need your help
I want to make a mobile application that connects to a databse on my laptop through internet without configuring my router
I'm using phpmyadmin in which i created a database, and I made a file called login.php that can make sure of username and password from database
I enabled the port 80 in firewall
now i wrote in eclipse this url : http:"//192.168.1.3:80/Day%20Manager/Login.php"
the ip address is optained by writing ipconfig in cmd and getting the IPV4 address
well it's not working it's giving me NetworkOnMainThreadException
can you help me please

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` --> do network related operations in another thread. Look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: Also check this question: [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: -1 for A/ poor formatting and B/ obvious lack of research

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [**link**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). This might help. Ofcourse if you are going to need to access it from your application you would have to provide an intermediary php script to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you said you are using phpmyadmin database, then place your php file in c:/>xampp/htdocs folder, open your browser and enter localhost/login.php then you will get output, in the same way connect to url from program then you will get the data.

```
note: make sure internet permission in manifest file.
```